# How can i checkout new code to server with git

Tags: git, version-control

With every deployment, I want to checkout the latest code in the `master` branch from the remote.

It is possible that people have changed the code on the server before the deployment, so I want the result of a deployment to only be the contents of the current tip of the `master` branch.

Currently, I use this:

```
git stash && git fetch origin && git reset --hard origin/master
```

Which works, but if I use `git status` then it says I am in the middle of a rebase. I'm unsure why it says this.

Rather than the above, is there any way I can `git checkout origin/master` every time I deploy so that no matter if there are any changes on the server, it just goes to `HEAD` of `master` every time?

Comment: I think you should be doing `git stash && git pull origin master`.  But if you don't mind having your changes on top of the latest `master` you could also do just `git pull --rebase origin master`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  if i do pull origin master then it try to merge the changes then if there is force push or there is some untrcaked file present  then it will complain  with something . I don't want to merge . I just want to go that state as that will be source of truth

Comment: Nothing wrong with this, except that you can't always throw your changes away each time.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i don't know about tags , but is it possble that with everypush i create new tag with buildnumber and i checkout those tag every time rather than with branches. Is it possible that if i checkout some tag1 and then do chnages and then again if i checkout anothe tag? will it complain

Comment: The use case you are presenting seems relatively atypical to me.  The most common use case you will face is that both your local `master` _and_ the remote `master` will each have changed since the last time you synched.  Your basic options are merging and rebasing, that's it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , I think you are right. Is it possible to git stash and then checkout tag , because local chnages don't matter me  and they should always be ignored. Suppose i am on tag1 with some some changes . can i do `git stash && git checkout tag2`

Comment: This should work, as a tag is really just an alias for a commit.